# How to count occurrences of int value in nested dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary looking

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> personStats
```

In my code it automatically generate new "persons" (keys) with a specific set of keys + values. First "string" is name and in the nested dictionary you have strings like "age", "height", "gender" with an attached int-value.

Example: John age: 20, height: 180, gender: 0 (0 is for  male).

In my case I would like to count how many times a specific int-value on a specific string occur. Example: I have a 100 persons (keys) in the dictionary, and I would like to know how many persons have the exact "age" of 43.

I've tried using `.Count`. Example: `personStats.Count()`, but of course it counts the first string (not to mention it doesn't take into account i want to cound a specific int-value). I've also tried with foreach, but I have no idea how to enter the nested dictionary to find the string "

Edit: Example of how I generate new keys. The parameters(personname,statType,value) comes from other methodes.

```
public void SetPersonStats(string personname, string statType, int value)
{

    if (personStats.ContainsKey(personname) == false)
    {
        personStats[personname] = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    personStats[personname][statType] = value;
}
```

So the parameters could be (John, age, 20), and (John, height, 180), and (John, gender, 0). So in the end I'll end up with the entry(?) John with 3 attached strings+value: age=20,heigh=180,gender=0. So imagine I ran this 100 times and got 100 different names with random ages, and I wanted to count how many had the age of 43.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of some example data? Generate one with some sample values, and what you're expecting.

Comment: Hi. I'll try (my code is a mess since I'm trying to learn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fetch you the number of users with age 42:

```
personStats.Count(c => c.Value["age"] == 42);
```

Ideally though, you should be using a class to define the person. Something like

```
enum Gender
{
     Male,
     Female
}
class PersonStats
{
    int Age;
    int Height;
    Gender Gender;
}


//Add to the dictionary
var dict = Dictionary<string, PersonStats>();
dict.Add("FrankerZ", new PersonStats{
   Age = 28,
   Height = 180,
   Gender = Gender.Male
});

//Some example filters:
dict.Count(person => person.Age == 28); //1
dict.Count(person => person.Gender == Gender.Male); //1
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to flatten this first with SelectMany seeing as the person attributes are within a nested dictionary and not accessible simply as part of personStats? So personStats kvps will constitute of a name and a dictionary of person attributes.

Comment: Thanks! This is just perfect - and ofc. it worked! I'll look in to your ideal version of it. But I have to take everything step for step since I'm still a neewbie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to count this:

```
var NumberPersonsAged43 =  personStats.SelectMany(p => p.Value["age"] == 43).Count();
```

This flattens your nested dictionaries using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx).